# disabled mat-select create accessibily problems

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

My problem is that I have  `mat-select` and after some operation I need to disabled it. The problem is that when I disable it I click on `tab` key and It doesn't select it for screen reader.

```
<mat-select [placeholder]="select_label" [(value)]="tipo_segnalazione" [disabled]="checkDisability()" tabindex="0">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let option of lista_tipo_segnalazione" [value]="option['cod']">
                    {{ option['description'] }}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
```

anyone can help me?